# Accuracy bad even after implementing deep neural net

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, floating-accuracy, sigmoid

my neural net is trying to predict whether a person has diabetes or not, This is my data set
[kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database).
I am using a 3 layered neural network and my accuracy is 65%. 
Any help for increasing the accuracy will be appreciated.

This is my code----------------------------------------------------------

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\manas\Downloads\diabetes.csv')

actualY=df['Outcome']
actualX=df.drop(['Outcome'],axis=1)
actualX=np.array(np.reshape(actualX,newshape=[768,8]))
actualY=np.array(np.reshape(actualY,newshape=[768,1]))
#Y=[768,1]
#X=[768,8]
x=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64,shape=[768,8])
W1=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((8,500)))
B1=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((1,1)))
y_prediction1=((tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),B1)))
output1=tf.nn.sigmoid(y_prediction1)
W2=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((500,600)))
B2=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((1,1)))
y_prediction2=((tf.add(tf.matmul(output1,W2),B2)))
output2=tf.nn.sigmoid(y_prediction2)
W3=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((600,1)))
B3=tf.Variable(dtype=np.float64,initial_value=np.random.random((1,1)))
y_prediction3=((tf.add(tf.matmul(output2,W3),B3)))


y_true=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64,shape=[768,1])

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_prediction3,labels=y_true))



optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


for i in range(200):
    (sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:actualX,y_true:actualY}))
     print(i,sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
    print(i)
prediction = tf.round(tf.sigmoid((y_prediction3)))

correct = tf.cast(tf.equal(prediction, y_true), dtype=np.float64)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct)
print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is quite small, you have to be carful while choosing the model parameters.

there are few things I don't understand from your code. It is a binary classification, right? if so, you should have a one-hot encoded output and GT with size of 2. In your code it seems you have only one output for every example! if you want to keep the GT as a vector, you should use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead.
Shouldn't you use softmax and `argmax` on `y_true` before comparing it to `prediction`? check that part as well.

if everything is fine with your code, I would consider these suggestions as well:

- reduce the number of hidden unites (e.g. 128 or 256)
- not sure why you are using biases with size (1,1), it should be a vector with the number of the output (i.e. in your example `B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500]))`)
- use Xavier init for the weights, and zero init for the biases
- add dropout layer if the network starts to overfit the training set
- try Adam opt and cross-validate the learning rates (or keep your current opt and change the learning rate)
- use small batch sizes (currently what you are doing is GD not SGB, which I think is more likely to stuck in local minima)
- use relu instead of sigmoid activation
- plot the learning curve and check if the network is training properly (i.e. the accuracy is increasing and the loss is decressing)

Anyways, with this small dataset you should easily overfit the training set. Getting 65% after 200 epoch clearly shows that there is something wrong with your model. Double check your code and make sure there is nothing wrong in it. You can use this [code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py) as an example.

UPDATE1:
You have to have one-hot encoded output! in your case it is with dimension 2. Check this code, I've made few modification on your code, but I didn't run it. Solve any possible bug and try to make it run:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\manas\Downloads\diabetes.csv')

actualY=df['Outcome']
actualX=df.drop(['Outcome'],axis=1)
actualX=np.array(np.reshape(actualX,newshape=[768,8]))
actualY=np.array(np.reshape(actualY,newshape=[768,1]))
#Y=[768,1]
#X=[768,8]

x = tf.placeholder('float',,shape=[None,8])
y_true = tf.placeholder('float',,shape=[None,1])

W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[8, 128],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=[128],initializer=initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1))

W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=[128, 128],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", shape=[128],initializer=initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h1,W2),b2))

W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape=[128, 2],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", shape=[2],initializer=initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(h2,W3),b3)


loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=tf.one_hot(y_true)))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


for i in range(200):
    sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:actualX,y_true:actualY})
    print(i,sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
    print(i)


pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), y_true)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
```

Comment: y_true is a 768,1 matrix which has only one value,(0 or 1) and sigmoid of y_prediction3 also gives only one value (0 or 1)... so isn't it fine that I use sigmoid_cross_entropy...(PS:I am a beginner in this so can you help me to implement tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits to solve the problem)

Comment: 2:I changed the bias dimension

Comment: Loss seems to be decreasing but after a point it becomes a constant 0.6412223

Comment: 4: Idk how to implement stochastic gradient descent

Comment: One thing I noticed with the output was that tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(y_prediction3))

Comment: always gives me a column vector full of zeros

Comment: So idk but I am thinking that 65% of my data is zeros so is it because of that and also why is it that after a point the gradientdescent stops to improve parameters

Comment: Overall thanks for the help but I was hoping you could help me solve this problem

Comment: Hi just saw this .. will implement and see if it works!

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i ran

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\manas\Downloads\diabetes.csv')

actualY=df['Outcome']
actualX=df.drop(['Outcome'],axis=1)
actualX=np.array(np.reshape(actualX,newshape=[768,8]))
actualY=np.array(np.reshape(actualY,newshape=[768,1]),dtype=int)
#Y=[768,1]
#X=[768,8]

x = tf.placeholder('float',shape=[None,8])
y_true = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1],dtype=tf.int64)

W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=[8, 
128],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=[128],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1))


W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=[128, 
128],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", shape=[128],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h1,W2),b2))

W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape=[128, 
2],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", shape=[2],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(h2,W3),b3)


loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=tf.one_hot(y_true,depth=2)))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(3000):
    sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:actualX,y_true:actualY})
    print(i,sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
    print(i)


pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.arg_max(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

print(sess.run(tf.round(tf.nn.softmax(logits)),feed_dict={x:actualX,y_true:actualY}))

print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: actualX, y_true: actualY}))
```

Although this gives a loss of `0.14772553`, it gives an accuracy of `64.564555 %`.

So I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: can you add the loss and accuracy plots?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: For each epoch save the loss and accuracy values and plot them after the training is done.